# MVC populate model with hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model:  `List<PROJECT>`

`PROJECT` -> having `List<TASK>`

`TASK`-> Having `List<SUBTASK>`

Data will be populated from Project,Task,Subtask tables respectively with reference to each.

What is the efficient way of populating This model with pagination?

**What I'm implementing:**

1. Select Project (first procedure call returns 10 project records(displaying 10 records ))
2. Select List of tasks based on ProjectID(second procedure called 10 times to bring task list under projects)
3. Select List of subtasks based on TaskID (third procedure called multiple times to bring subtask list under tasks)

This solution is working fine but require multiple database calls.

**Update**

```
 public List<Project> GetProject(int page=1, int pageSize=10)
    {
        List<Project> _lstProject = new List<Project>();
        try
        {
            using (DevEntities db = new DevEntities())
            {
                _lstProject = db.ProjectSelect(page, pageSize).Select(m => new Project()
                {
                    ProjectId = m.ProjectID,
                    ProjectNumber = m.ProjectNo,
                    TaskList = GetTaskDetails(m.ProjectID)

                }).ToList();

            }
            return _lstProject ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            _lstProject = null;
        }
    }

public List<Task> GetTaskDetails(ProjectID)
    {
        List<Task> _lstTask = new List<Task>();
        try
        {
            using (DevEntities db = new DevEntities())
            {
                _lstTask = db.TaskSelect(ProjectID).Select(m => new Task()
                {
                    TaskId = m.TaskID,
                    TaskNumber = m.TaskNo,
                    SubTaskList = GetSubTaskDetails(m.TaskID)

                }).ToList();

            }
            return _lstTask ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            _lstTask = null;
        }
    }

public List<SubTask> GetSubTaskDetails(int TaskID)
    {
        List<SubTask> _lstSubTask = new List<SubTask>();
        try
        {
            using (DevEntities db = new DevEntities())
            {
                _lstSubTask = db.TaskSelect(TaskID).Select(m => new SubTask()
                {
                    SubTaskId = m.SubTaskID,
                    SubTaskNumber = m.SubTaskNo
                }).ToList();

            }
            return _lstSubTask ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            _lstSubTask = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness of your screen a little? It's a bit difficult to see any code you've already got...

Comment: When you get those 10 projects you could also populate tasks and subtasks for these projects. That means one query for every 10 projects. How do you access your DB? Are you using ADO, EF, NHibernate?

Comment: do you use entity framework as ORM?

Comment: YES using EF for accessing DB

Comment: @GeoffJames Question updated. Is it visible now?

Comment: As a side note, `catch` with `throw` is redundant. Simply avoid the `catch` clause and keep only `finally`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, in order to optimize your code you have two valid options:

**Option 1:**

One query for each entity type (total 3 queries):

```
var projects = db.Projects.Where().Order().Skip().Take().Select().ToList(); // 1 query
var projectIds = projects.Select(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();

var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(x => projectIds.Contains(x.ProjectId)).Select().ToList(); // 1 query
var taskIds = tasks.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var subtasks = db.Tasks.Where(x => taskIds.Contains(x.TaskId)).Select().ToList() // 1 query

foreach(var project in projects)
{
    project.Tasks = tasks.Where(x => x.ProjectId == project.ProjectId).ToList();

    // etc
    // complete hierarchy structure
}
```

**Option 2:**

One query with 2 left outer joins:

```
var projects = (from proj in db.Projects.Where()

                join t in db.Tasks on t.ProjectId equals proj.ProjectId into tasks
                from task in t.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join s in db.Tasks on s.TaskId equals task.Id into subtasks
                from subtask in subtasks.DefaultIfEmpty()

                select new 
                {
                    ProjectId = proj.ProjectId,
                    TaskId = task.Id,
                    SubtaskId = subtask.Id

                }).ToList(); // 1 query

// etc
// proceed with creating hierarchy structure using GroupBy
```

Which one of these two is more efficient ?

It depends. I'm sure there are a lot of people which prefer one over the other and i would actually be happy to hear their comments.

My **personal** experience taught me to usually choose **Option 1**, but you should test and time both of them based on your data volume and db configuration (indexes, fks) and decide for yourself